# Is there something wrong with my function arguments or is it something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Have this function but it doesn't seem to execute correctly. Here it is:

```
       function chooseCols(colTag,tagName) {
            // Set name column
            var column = $('.tagChooser:eq('+ colTag +')');         
            column.parents('.col').css('background','#EAF3EA');
            column.val(tagName);            
        } setTimeout(chooseCols(data.col_name,'colName'), 2000);
```

With execute correctly I mean that the right select option is not chosen and the background color of it's parent stays the same.

**OH btw, data.col_name is a json object I get from an ajax call. It gives me an index I can use for selecting the right .**

Any tips are welcome!!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
  function chooseCols(colTag,tagName) {
     // Set name column
     var column = $('.tagChooser:eq('+ colTag +')');         
     column.parents('.col').css('background','#EAF3EA');
     column.val(tagName);            
  } 
  setTimeout(function () {
      chooseCols(data.col_name,'colName');
  }, 2000);
```

Your problem is because you invoke your function (`chooseCols(data.col_name,'colName')`) and pass `undefined` instead of function to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

Passing argunments should be like this

```
setTimeout(function(){
    chooseCols(data.col_name,'colName')
}, 2000);
```